# Can't receive Async response in componentDidMount with Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios, redux-thunk

lately i'm facing a tough issue with React/Redux (Thunk): i've created my Store with Action and Reducer properly, in my Component i trigger the Async function in componentDidMount method in order to update the state, But the State doesn't seems to be changing, although it does changed in componentDidUpdate and mapStateToProps functions ! Why ? Here is my code :

```
export const getAllInterventions = () => {
return dispatch => {
    dispatch(getAllDataStart());
    axios.get('/interventions.json')
        .then(res => {
            dispatch(getAllDataSuccess(res.data));
        })
        .catch(err => {
            dispatch(getAllDataFail(err));
        });
};
```

My reducer :

```
case actionTypes.GET_ALL_INTERVENTIONS_SUCCESS:
        return {
            ...state,
            interventions: interventions: action.interventions
        };
```

My Component:

```
    componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getAllInterventions();
    console.log('DidMount: ', this.props.inter); /*Empty Array Or Undefined */
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
console.log('mapStateToProps', state);
return {
    inter: state.interventions,
    error: state.error
};
```

Comment: case actionTypes.GET_ALL_INTERVENTIONS_SUCCESS:
        return {
            ...state,
            interventions: interventions: action.interventions
        }; Please check the above code in reducer I think it should be interventions: action.interventions

Comment: No sorry i've just mistyped that, I've tried this with all actions but I've got the same problem, i think like the component finish mounting before the request is completed

Comment: I think you need some kind of spinner or indicator for showing unresolved promise. You can use some variable to like loading:true and set this to false inside your reducer once resolved. Use the same loading inside the render function to show spinner.

Comment: I've used redux devtool, I've found out that the state has all the data, but the component can't receive that full state in first call, until didUpdate!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your action and state changes are both asynchronous, doing `console.log` right after will always return before those changes are actually completed.

Your state is being updated, which is why it works when you `console.log` in the mapStateToProps.

I suggest setting up redux-devtools, you'll be able to easily track your actions/state.

Comment: Yes I did that, I've found out that the state has all the data, but the component can't receive that full state in first call, until didUpdate  !!!!

Comment: Not sure what you mean...your component on mount makes a http request, finishes rendering, then once the request is done it will update your component with the data returned from the request. You might want to pass another variable on success/error to let your component know that the data has returned and render the component based on that.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the code can be usefully for you

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){  
    console.log(nextProps.inter)
}
```